# Remote Web Access Resources

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services, windows

I have a client who has been using the Remote Web Access in SBS 2011. They had access to each of their domain PC's that were on the same network after logging into the RD Gateway.

I'm trying to duplicate the same config on Server 2012 R2. I've gotten as far as being able to login to the RD Gateway but I'm unable to add resources. When I choose "Add RD Session host server" I'm only able to add the server and no domain PC's.

Does anyone know how to add domain PC's as a RD session host?

Comment: I haven't used that in Windows Server 2012 or R2 but `RD Session Host Servers` are servers that have the RDS Session Host role installed, not computers or other servers that don't have the RD Session Host role installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

typical Microsoft giving us a shortage of information :D

What you need to do is connect the computers using the following tool
`<your domain name for Anywhere Access>/connect`

for example : `example.be/connect`

This will install a windows update and start configuring your PC placing it on the domain etc

After this, your devices will become visible on the dashboard.
Now you'll want to go to the properties of the users and add the devices to the users.

Now they show up for those users when they go to the web portal

But, I'm currently not able to connect yet :(
Still more errors I'm currently trying to solve, I hope this help!